# Get RNN cell activations in Keras/Tensorflow2 when return_sequences = False

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a simple seq2seq autoencoder in tensorflow (e.g. from [this notebook](https://github.com/timsainb/tensorflow2-generative-models/blob/master/4.0-seq2seq-fashion-mnist.ipynb)), where the encoder and decoder are `tf.keras.Sequential` objects.

[image: seq2seq]

When training the model, I only want to pass the FINAL state of the LSTM layers to Z. So in tensorflow/keras I set `return_sequences` to `False` (e.g. `LSTM(... return_sequences=False)`).

However, in post-hoc analyses, I want to be able to look at the trajectory of the RNN cell activations throughout the sequence. **How can I access RNN cell activations when `return_sequences = False` in Tensorflow/Keras?**

Comment: ...use `return_sequences=True`? You can just use something like `states[:, -1, :]` (assuming `time_major=False`) during training to only get the last time step.

Comment: @xdurch0 I know I can return those values and then only pass the last state to the next part of the network. I want to know whether I can do so without having to rewrite the structure of the network. E.g. without having to break the encoder/decoder up into multiple `tf.keras.Sequential` objects.